# Add Image Control inside DataList Template through C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, datalist

I want to insert asp image control inside datalist Itemtemplate through C#. Here is the code below i am currently trying but it didn't work.

```
DataList DataListCampaign = new DataList();
DataListCampaign.RepeatLayout = RepeatLayout.Flow ;
DataListCampaign.RepeatDirection = System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeatDirection.Horizontal;
DataListCampaign.DataSource = CampTabImage;
DataListCampaign.DataBind();
Image TabImages = new Image();
TabImages.ID = "TabImages";
DataListCampaign.Controls.Add(TabImages);
TabContainer1.Tabs[k].Controls.Add(DataListCampaign);
```

Where is the problem??

Comment: <asp:DataList ID="DataList2" runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
       <asp:Image ID="Image4" runat="server" />
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
How can we achieve this thing dynamically through C# as i pasted code inside the comment above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with this

```
     Image TabImages = new Image();
     TabImages.ID = "TabImages";
     TabImages.ImageUrl = "~/imagepath";
     DataListCampaign.Items[0].Controls.Add(TabImages);
```